# Parsing error on tail recursion Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I have the following code to compute the sum of all the elements of a list.

```
sum_list_tail :: [Int] -> Int
sum_list_tail ( x:xs ) = inc( x:xs, 0 )
                            where inc( x:xs, a ) =
                                if ( x:xs == [] ) then a
                                    else inc( xs, a+x )
```

I try to use tail recursion to solve this problem.

I have this error `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)` occurring at this line `if ( x:xs == [] ) then a`

Can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you mixing tabs & spaces? Haskell hates that. Also this test `x:xs == []` is constant `False`. Probably not what you meant to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **syntactical error**, is due to the fact that the spaces are not equal in the where clause: the `if` statement has less spaces than the `where` line. You can thus easily resolve it by writing a one-liner in the `where` clauses:

```
sum_list_tail :: [Int] -> Int
sum_list_tail ( x:xs ) = inc( x:xs, 0 )
    where inc( x:xs, a ) = if ( x:xs == [] ) then a else inc( xs, a+x )
```

Nevertheless there is still a **semantical error**: the **`x:xs` cannot be equal to `[]`. So the `if` statement will always** be false. You can solve this by working with **pattern matching**:

```
sum_list_tail :: [Int] -> Int
sum_list_tail ( x:xs ) = inc( x:xs, 0 )
    where inc( [], a ) = a
          inc ( x:xs, a ) = inc( xs, a+x )
```

Nevertheless, to me it does *not* feel very *Haskell-ish*. Usually you do not work with tuples, but with multiple arguments, like:

```
sum_list_tail :: [Int] -> Int
sum_list_tail ls = inc ls 0
    where inc []     a = a
          inc (x:xs) a = inc xs a+x
```

Furthermore there is already a `sum` defined: [`sum :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum).

If you want to define a `sum`, you can also use for instance `foldl`:

```
sum_list_tail :: (Num b, Foldable t) => t b -> b
sum_list_tail = foldl (+) 0
```

Comment: Thanks, very detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

The more natural recursion to solve this (if you are not familiar with foldr or foldl) would be this:

```
sum_list_tail :: [Int] -> Int
sum_list_tail  [] = 0 
sum_list_tail (x:xs) = x+ sum_list_tail xs
```